# Keep track of wins in my tic tac toe application VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I've written a Tic Tac Toe application in VB 2010 and it runs well, but I'd like to be able to keep track of the number of wins for X's and O's and/or Player 1 and Player 2. I've tried adding in do while loops, but I'm pretty ignorant as to how to correctly implement them and I'm unsure if that's even the correct way to track wins..  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub


Private Sub btn11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn11.Click
    'clos the form
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btn10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn10.Click
    btn1.Enabled = True
    btn2.Enabled = True
    btn3.Enabled = True
    btn4.Enabled = True
    btn5.Enabled = True
    btn6.Enabled = True
    btn7.Enabled = True
    btn8.Enabled = True
    btn9.Enabled = True
    btn1.Text = ""
    btn2.Text = ""
    btn3.Text = ""
    btn4.Text = ""
    btn5.Text = ""
    btn6.Text = ""
    btn7.Text = ""
    btn8.Text = ""
    btn9.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn1.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn1.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    btn1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn2.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn2.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn2.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn3.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn3.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn4.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn4.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn4.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn5.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn5.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn5.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn6.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn6.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn6.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn7.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn7.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn7.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn8.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn8.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn8.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    If lbl2.Text = "X" Then
        btn9.Text = "X"
        lbl2.Text = "O"
    Else
        btn9.Text = "O"
        lbl2.Text = "X"
    End If
    Call win()
    btn9.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub win()
    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn2.Text = "X" And btn3.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn4.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn6.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn7.Text = "X" And btn8.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn4.Text = "X" And btn7.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn2.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn8.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn3.Text = "X" And btn6.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn3.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn7.Text = "X" Then
        lbl2.Text = "X wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn1.Text = "O" And btn2.Text = "O" And btn3.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn4.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn6.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn7.Text = "O" And btn8.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn1.Text = "O" And btn4.Text = "O" And btn7.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn2.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn8.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn3.Text = "O" And btn6.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn1.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btn3.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn7.Text = "O" Then
        lbl2.Text = "O wins"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare Variables in your Class and keep track of the wins using those variables.  By keeping them in the Class, as opposed to your Win() Method, they will not be reset to 0 the next time someone clicks a button that calls Win().

```
Private m_intPlayerOneWins As Integer = 0
Private m_intPlayerTwoWins As Integer = 0
```

Then in your Win() Method:

```
'If X Wins
m_intPlayerOneWins += 1
```

Or

```
'If O Wins
m_intPlayerTwoWins += 1
```